# Jellyfin Android Tv server connection error

Tags: android, television

well am new on Jellyfin and I was trying to connect to my server using the android tv app and experienced this error: "Server uses version 10.7.7 which is not supported" , how can I resolve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the lastest version of the server (currently 10.8.1) and update your client app.
Also check your network configuration to see if your firewall doesn't block the connection.
If not working on latest versions it will be better making a issue on the repo : https://github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin-androidtv/issues